# Cannot talk to asp.net server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, iui

Totally n00b question, Im making my first ASP.NET website, with the added twist of using IUI framework that makes things look nice on the iPhone.

1. **How do I hookup the whitebutton to go and verify the user and password on the database?**
2. **How do I make the brower go to a different window if the password was good else...**
3. **How do I append a message like "password incorrect" on the current page?**

I am a c# programmer by default and totally lost in this new field. Please not I cannot make an  it doesnt seem to work with IUI.

**Master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Cover_Plus.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="iui/iui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link title="default" href="iui/t/default/default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="iui/iui.js"></script>

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/touch-icon-iphone.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/touch-icon-ipad.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/startup.png" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Cover Plus" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Cover_Plus._Default" %>

<%--Header--%>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</asp:Content>

<%--Body--%>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<div class="toolbar">
    <h1 id="pageTitle">System Login</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel" selected="true" id="loginPanel"> 

    <h2>Login to Cover Plus</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="ident" text="hhh" placeholder="Your login" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <form id="Form1" title="Index" name="formname" method="POST">
        <a class="whiteButton" type="submit" href="javascript:formname.submit()">Login me in!</a>
   </form>
</div>


</asp:Content>
```

**UPDATE :**

I think a screenshot may be helpful.

[image]

The problem is that "whitebutton" seems to be what I have to use, its not like an asp.net server side button, thus I cannot simply double click to hookup the click event.

I tried Humpty Dumptys method, but it doesnt call the Verify() method in my .CS file at all. I tried with just onclick="Login();" instead  of Javascript:Login(); both dont work.

UPDATE 2:

The  works at the bottom, but as soon as I replace the Input to Textbox see what happens ...

[image]

Many Thanks In Advance

**Final Solution :**

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1 id="pageTitle">Login</h1>
</div>

<div id="pnlLogin" class="panel" selected="true" >
    <h2>Login Details</h2>
    <form ID="fLogin" runat="server" class="panel" selected="true" > 
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <label>Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox id="txtUserName" runat="server" placeholder="Your username" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label>Password</label>
                <asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" textmode="Password" runat="server" placeholder="Your password" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <asp:LinkButton id="btnLogin" class="whiteButton" text="Log me in!" runat="server" onclick="Login_Clicked" />
    </form> 
</div>
```

**Basically the form was decorated with "class=panel" and the asp: style controls were used to connect to the backend.**

Comment: do you want to verify the user against your database?? And are you using asp.net membership provider??

Comment: Hi yes I am, the db is on the server, I can handle all that fine, I just dont know how to go back and forth from the client to the server and to access the username and password from the server.

Comment: Have you read the tutorials on http://www.asp.net/web-forms?

Comment: jrummel : I tried to read through many websites for a couple of hours before I asked here. But thanks Ill have a look at ur link it may help me later.

Comment: @MuhammadA : you should use asp.net controls in your code. eg **<asp:TextBox ID="txbUsername" Text="User name" runat="server" />** seems like you are trying to validate user in client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebForms, as it appears you're using, generally has a page-wide `<form runat="server">`. This will usually be defined as part of the MasterPage (`~/Site.master` in your case) and can usually be found just a few lines after the `<body>` tag.

If your site has this form, communication with the server is then handled through server-side Controls (marked with `runat="server"`):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Username" Text="hhh" runat="server"
    placeholder="Your Login" />

<asp:TextBox ID="Password" TextMode="Password" runat="server"
    placeholder="Your password" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="Login" Text="Login me in!" runat="server"
    CssClass="whitebutton" OnClick="Login_Clicked" />
```

> Each server-side control represents regular HTML that it generates during rendering, so the above would become something like this:
>
> ```
> <input id="ct100_Username" name="ct100$Username" type="text" value="hhh" placeholder="Your Login" />
>
> <input id="ct100_Password" name="ct100$Password" type="password" placeholder="Your password" />
>
> <a id="ct100_Login" class="whitebutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ct100$Login','')">Login me in!</a>
> ```
>
> (Note: The actual client-side IDs and names may be a lot different than the examples here.)

The `ID` attributes of these server-side controls are generally mapped to properties/fields of the `Page` class, so `this.Username` will return the `TextBox` instance representing the 1st `<asp:TextBox />`.

With `AutoEventWireup="True"`, as you have, you would then define the method that was specified in the `OnClick` of the `<asp:LinkButton />` as part of the `Page` class:

```cs
protected void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = Username.Text;
    var pass = Password.Text;

    if (ValidateUser(user, pass))
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly when I add an <asp:button> to the page it messes the whole thing up, as per IUI tutorial Im using that "whitebutton" code.

Comment: @MuhammadA You can set that on the button with the `CssClass` attribute -- `CssClass="whitebutton"`. But, you may also want to use a `<asp:LinkButton />` specifically -- this will be sent to the browser as an `<a />` rather than an `<input type="submit" />`.

Comment: @MuhammadA Also, make sure that the `<form runat="server">` isn't already defined within the `~/Site.master` MasterPage. If it is, having it within the current page (as your "Update 2" shows) would be redundant and possibly breaking -- the HTML spec doesn't support forms within forms and WebForms isn't designed for that either.

Comment: I added the master file. Please see it does not contain any form tag. I think this may be to do with the css/js file from the IUI Framework http://www.iui-js.org/documentation/latest/getting-started.html ... They may not be coded to apply styles to the textbox control.

Answer (score 2):

You have to validate the user details on your `buttonclick` event.

If you have a database fields to `username` and `password` you can create a function which accept username and password and verify against the database.

eg. in your button click event you can do something similar

```
var status = verifyUser(username,password);//might return Boolean value 
if(!status)
      somelable.text = "username or password incorrect";
else
     // do something - redirect to some page may be
```

also have a read at this article about [Validating ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx) and if you willing to use asp.net membership provider,[Use Membership in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) and [Validating User Credentials Against the Membership User](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs)

---

if use still not understand ...

modify your code something similar to this

**your fronted**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Name :</label>            
            <asp:TextBox ID="txbUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Password :</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txbPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass ="whiteButton" 
                onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</asp:Content>
```

**Your Backend**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var username = txbUserName.Text;
        var password = txbPassword.Text;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            if(!VerifyUser(username,password))
            {
                lblError.Text = "username or password incorrect";
            }
        }
    }
    // I recommend this function to be in a separate class but for example 
    public static Boolean VerifyUser(string username,string password)
    {
        //
        return true or false
    }
```

Comment: Do I put this code into the script part at the top of the page? And the verifyUser() should be in the backend cs file?

Comment: it is better if you create a separate class to access the data where you can create your **validateuser** and you can call it in your backend